# Reference Levels for film mix

Tags: mixing, techniques

Are blu rays a good source for referencing film mixes. I know Dvd's are not coz they are extremely compressed. If blu rays are not where can i get hold of some film mixes for reference?

Answer (score 1):

Most DVD mixes tend to actually be pretty dynamic (relative to the theatrical). On lower budget indies and whatnot there often is no difference between the theatrical and DVD/Blu-Ray.

As far as references go, calibrate your room (lots of great online resources for that) and then pick some movies that sound like you want yours to sound and listen to them in your room at whatever mix level you're using (79-85) and just teach your ears, basically.

Answer (score 0):

what is the reference you're looking for? loudness or something else?
loudness: it totally depends on the monitoring system and the room. if you have your room and speakers properly calibrated you won't need to listen to a mix for reference.
dvd's are not always "extremely compressed". there are some great sounding dvd's, like 'saving private ryan'.

cheers